# Run php script with grunt

Tags: php, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have a php script (lets call this /test.php) on my server. After Grunt automatically has parsed my SCSS and JS I would like to run this test.php script (it resets my memcache). I can't seem to find a way to do this. Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to run your php script on cli via `php -f your-script.php`

```
grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
        php: {
            command: 'php -f your-script.php'
        }
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('runTestPhp', ['shell:php']);
```

If you don't want to run your php script through cli, have a look at [grunt-php](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php).